# Table with a scrollbar inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a look at the short example.

[Bootply with sample table](http://www.bootply.com/ZVR7BCvhT2)

How can I add a horizontal and vertical `scroll` across the div that contains the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are finding for something like this: [**Bootply example**](http://www.bootply.com/kd8LTMIdzR)

I used `overflow: scroll;` for the `.table-responsive`

More on that @ **[w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)**

Comment: how can i give the table a fixed height?

Comment: @user2281858 why would you use Bootstrap 3 if you want your table to be of a fixed height? Create your own then with fixed widths and heights using ``overflow: scroll``, because basically it won't work with bootstrap's table. And the question was about the scrollbar, not about the fixed height.

Comment: Do you mean a fixed height for the tables container (`.table-responsive`) with a scroll? [Like this](http://www.bootply.com/yz4zUvpfFK)?